# How to retrieve only the file name in a s3 folders path using pyspark

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, pyspark, boto3

Hi I have aws s3 bucket in which few of the folders and subfolders are defined

I need to retrieve only the filename in whichever folder it will be. How to go about it

> ```
> s3 bucket name - abc
>
> path - s3://abc/ann/folder1/folder2/folder3/file1
>
> path - s3://abc/ann/folder1/folder2/file2
> ```

code tried so far

```
   s3 = boto3.client(s3)
   lst_obj = s3.list_objects(bucket='abc',prefix='ann/')
   lst_obj["contents"]
```

I'm further looping to get all the contents

```
   for file in lst_obj["contents"]:
         do somtheing...
```

Here file["Key"] gives me the whole path, but i just need the filename

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can just extract the name by splitting the file `Key` on `/` symbol and extracting last element

```
for file in lst_obj["contents"]:
       name = file["Key"].split("/")[-1]
```

Answer (score 6):

Here is an example of how to get the filenames.

```
import boto3

s3 = boto3.resource('s3')

for obj in s3.Bucket(name='<your bucket>').objects.filter(Prefix='<prefix>'):
    filename = obj.key.split('/')[-1]
    print(filename)
```

Answer (score 1):

Using list objects even with a prefix is simply filtering objects that start with a specific prefix.

What you see as a path in S3 is actually part of the objects key, in fact the key (which is acting as a piece of metadata to identify the object) actually has the value including what might look as if they're subfolders.

If you want the last part of the object key, you will need to split the key by the separator ('/').

You could do this with `file['Key'].rsplit(',')[1]` which would give you the filename.